# How can I move files by type recursively from a directory and its sub-directories to another directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, find, rename

What would be a good way to move a file type from a directory and all of its sub-directories?

Like "move all *.ogg in /thisdir recursively to /somedir". I tried a couple of things; my best effort was (still not that great):

```
find /thisdir -type f -name '*.ogg' -exec mv /somedir {} \;
```

It returned on each line before each file name,

```
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `/thisdir/*.ogg' with directory `/somedir'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can use find with [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) for this

`find /thisdir -type f -name "*.ogg" -print0 | xargs -0 -Imysongs mv -i mysongs /somedir`

> The -I in the above command tells
>   xargs what replacement string you want
>   to use (otherwise it adds the
>   arguments to the end of the command).

OR
In your command just try to move '{}' after `mv` command.

`find /thisdir -type f -name '*.ogg' -exec mv -i {} /somedir  \;`

Comment: please don't forget to take backup before trying above commands :-).

Comment: Btw, for the first -print0 for find and -0 for xargs should be used as possible, to avoid whitespace in filename problems.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: good point. I will edit.

Comment: I strongly suggest using `mv -i` here, so you don't risk overwriting files if something unexpected happens.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks :). This is the reason I love stackexchange. Not only we help others but learn also :). one more edit.

Comment: with mv from gnu core utils you can use `mv -t <targetdir>` and + instead of \;

Answer (score 17):

In zsh or bash 4, to gather all `*.ogg` files into `/somedir`:

```
mv /thisdir/**/*.ogg /somedir
```

If you wanted to reproduce the directory hierarchy: (warning, typed directly into the browser)

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include='*/' --include='*.ogg' --exclude='*' /thisdir /somedir
```

Comment: beyond convenient in bash

Answer (score 16):

```
find /thisdir -type f -name "*.ogg" -exec mv {} /somedir \;
```

You kinda interchanged the arguments for mv

Comment: WARNING!!! This does not keep the recursive folder structure at the destination!

Answer (score 1):

i got "directory not empty" error.
to fix this i run:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec mkdir -p ./another/dir/{} \; -exec mv -i {} ./NODE_MODULES/{} \;
```

this will keep the directory structure.