# What does the -I argument do from xargs?

Tags: shell-script, xargs

I am writing a bash script and encountered this argument `-I` in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970972/copy-or-move-all-files-in-a-directory-regardles-of-folder-depth-or-number#:%7E:text=find%20/absolute/path/to/Pictures%20%2Dname%20%27*.png%27%20%7C%20xargs%20%2DI%20files%20mv%20files%20/absolute/path/to/results) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-can-i-move-files-by-type-recursively-from-a-directory-and-its-sub-directorie#:%7E:text=find%20/thisdir%20%2Dtype%20f%20%2Dname%20%22*.ogg%22%20%2Dprint0%20%7C%20xargs%20%2D0%20%2DImysongs%20mv%20%2Di%20mysongs%20/somedir) but I do not understand what it does. The [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/xargs.1posix.html#:%7E:text=%2DI%20replstr%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Insert,be%20forced%20on.) is also not clear to me.

The second answer also states the following text which I also don't understand:

> ```
> find /thisdir -type f -name "*.ogg" -print0 | xargs -0 -Imysongs mv -i mysongs /somedir
> ```
>
> The `-I` in the above command tells `xargs` what replacement string you want to use (otherwise it adds the arguments to the end of the command).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it is kind of roundabout description, but ultimately it is very simple:
`-I` defines a pattern. That pattern would be searched in the remaining of the command line and replaced with an input from stdin.

In the example you shown:

```
xargs -0 -Imysongs mv -i mysongs /somedir
```

The `-I` defines a pattern "mysongs", that pattern is searched in the rest of command line.

In you example, `find` produces a list of .ogg files. These files are coming to `xarg`. So for each file name found by `find`, the `xarg` will create and execute command

```
mv -i <filename> /somedir
```